# machines of two subnets communicate through CentOS(with two NICs)

Tags: centos, gateway, nic

folks.
Firstly, I really have done a lot of searching, but still couldn't find a problem which was exactly the same as mine, and I have tried some of their answers, but didn't work. Finally, I put my problem here.

I have a machine **C** with two NICs, namely *eth0* and *eth1*, with CentOS 4.9 installed on it. Also I have a machine **A** connecting to **C** through *eth0* and a machine **B** connecting to **C** through *eth1*. Now I want machine **A** to be in a subnet(e.g. 192.168.1.0/24) and machine **B** to be in another subnet(e.g. 192.168.2.0/24) and they could communicate with each other.

For example, here is a scenario

A:192.168.1.100
B:192.168.2.100

In machine A, the command **ping 192.168.2.100** could return correctly, and vice vesa.

Above is my demand. But I don't know how to do it. Any suggestions will be appreciated. Hope make myself clear.

Thanks in advance.

Jfhu

Comment: Can you show the output of `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`and `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1` ? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

- Give machine C an IP address on `eth0` in the subnet `192.168.1.0/24`, and an IP address on `eth0` in the subnet `192.168.2.0/24` (I use `.254` for all my routers, but others prefer `.1` -- it's a personal choice).
- Configure machine A to have a default gateway of whatever IP address you put on machine C's `eth0`, and give machine B the default gateway of the IP you put on machine C's `eth1`.
- Make sure that machine C has IP forwarding turned on, and any relevant `iptables` rules are not going to block the traffic you want to allow through.

And you're away.

Comment: I'd further add that instead of setting the default gateway, you could add a static route for `192.168.2.0/24` on A set to go through C, and the `.1.0/24` on B going through C. But that only matters if you also have Internet connectivity through some host. If this is just a local network it doesn't matter.

Comment: I took a literal interpretation of the question, mostly to keep the OP's head from exploding.

Comment: Thanks all for your help. To womble, could you please give me the iptables rules I should add in the case of my example in the answer.

Comment: Why not give it a go yourself, and if you get stuck, ask a new question on Server Fault?  You'll learn more if you try it yourself first.

Comment: To womble, thanks, Now I haven't add any rules, but it works.

Comment: So sorry for reporting wrong results. Actually it doesn't work. Only machine C could ping machine A, and I have added one rule: iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE. It seems like all packets will go to the eth0, not eth1. I have not much knowledge about iptables. So any one guide me some tutorials?

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.  Protip, though: I didn't mention using NAT in my answer, because it is not required.  Don't use it.

Comment: Sorry for question nesting. I have read the manual of iptables command roughly. It seems to me that the iptables -t filter -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o eth1 -j ACCEPT should works default, however it didn't. So I still couldn't get machine A,B ping each other normally. Any specific instruction? Sorry for my stupidity

Comment: Questions go in questions, not comments.